# Anyone have luck getting graphics working with an NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M (iMac)?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Here's what I've tried so far:

- running stock drivers installed by Ubuntu 14.04 default install: system is very slow, laggy and jumpy.
- installing nvidia-current: system boots up to black screen, has to be hard-reboot, and Ubuntu completely reinstalled.
- installing current drivers from Nvidia website: TTYs don't work, "swrast" module can't be loaded, which means Unity doesn't work, and in other window managers, unity-control-center and other utilities don't work.

I'm scared to try installing other NVIDIA drivers, since this is a production machine, and I don't want to brick it. Does anyone have any advice for the best configuration for this card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to get this to work by adding the xorg-edgers PPA and installing the latest proprietary NVIDIA driver there.